# How do I make a triangular trihedral with 90degree planes?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I am new to blender and I want to make a triangular trihedral which has 90 degrees between the planes. I have already tried the cone with 3 planes but this did not work the way I wanted it to since the measurements were off.

Answer (score 5):

- Enable the shipped add-on 'Add Mesh: Extra Objects'
- Spin up a 'Math Function > Regular Solid'. It should default to a regular tetrahedron, radius 1.
- Scale it in XY with <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>.

**EDIT:**

As @Gordon Brinkmann points out, you don't need the 'Extra Objects' add on. Alternatively, you could:

- Create a 3-sided cone, radius 1, depth `sqrt(2)/2`, (or, `1/sqrt(2)`, if you prefer typing that) .

[image]

Comment: A regular tetrahedron you can also get with the regular cone set to 3 and scaling it on Z, which is explicitly mentioned in the question to be not working. A regular tetrahedron doesn't have 90° angles, this doesn't change if you scale it on XY by 2.

Comment: Ha, you're right - since the usual depiction of a trihedral in radar technology is always having it stand upright on the orthogonal corner, I just didn't realize that. Well, so you don't need _Extra Objects_, the cone will work too, just have to scale it differently. Guess that's why the OP didn't get to work it out. Only problem is, if you want the "usual" orientation, you will also have to rotate it... depends on what the OP wants.

Comment: Ah, with the edit it's much easier to recognize. +1 Now the only thing that's missing is how to calculate the radius if the OP needs a special length for the catheti - since the question states "the measurements were off", I imagine that maybe the dimensions are required to be correct as well.

Answer (score 4):

**//EDIT:** Just a quick mathematical information on the answers by @RobinBetts and myself, in case you need the trihedral to have specified dimension on the catheti:

Let's say the length should be ***a***, then construct it with the following dimensions:

**1. Cube:**

- *Size* = ***a*** meters in XYZ direction

**2. Cone:**

- *Vertices* = 3
- *Radius 1* = ***a*** × sqrt(3/2)
- *Depth* = ***a*** / sqrt(3)

Then use either 1. the Cube method or 2. the Cone method.

Cube method:

1. I take a cube, select two bottom vertices that are diagonally opposite to each other and press <kbd>J</kbd> to connect them.

[image: cube]

2. Then I select all vertices apart from the bottom triangle I want to keep, at last the one in the top corner above the bottom triangle (showing in white as the active selection) and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge* > *At Last*.

[image: merging]

3. Now I have a tetrahedron with three 90° angles.

[image: tetrahedron]

4. I select the front diagonal face, delete it with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Faces* and have a trihedral.

[image: trihedral]

Another method would be, after step 1 above, "connecting the opposite vertices" you could go on like that:

2. Select those two vertices at the front edge and delete them with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Vertices*.

[image: front edge]

3. Now select the top vertices of the remaining two squares and dissolve them with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Vertices*.

[image: dissolve]

And you already have a trihedral:

[image: result]

Comment: Snappy!   This cuts one move off my method :D

Comment: @RobinBetts Which extra move did you have? :)

Comment: I used a _Bisect_.  I don't need the deletion on your version? .. Depends what OP wants, I guess.

Comment: @RobinBetts While I was waiting for your answer I edited my answer to a second method, another step less.

Comment: I tried with _Bisect_, but I think it's not so easy to get the correct angle, since all three should be isosceles triangles of the same size, with all catheti having a length of _a_ and the hypotenuses a length of _a_*_sqrt(2)_.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a plane, rotate it as reference, and edit the cone with snapping to fit it with reference.[image]